# Resolving nunjucks templates from NPM ( node modules )?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, npm, nunjucks

Looking for a way to get nunjucks imports / includes to resolve from the NPM `node_modules` folder.

For example suppose we have a package installed like this:

```
npm i -S @example/cards
```

We now want to import from it like this within a template:

```
{% import "@example/templates/birthday.html" as birthday %}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Hmm, doesn't `nunjucks.configure('node_modules', ...` solve your problem?

Comment: Ideally nunjucks.render() would just understand that something that is not preceded with a `/` or `.` or `..` is a node module and then use the same resolv algorithm that node uses...and this should be something that can be built into for example a CLI and always work without any additional configuration.

Comment: Put in a feature request: https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks/issues/1136

Comment: You can write a simple custom [loader](http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#writing-a-loader).

Comment: Aha!  Sweet - I'm going to have to have a serious look at that.  Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @AikonMogwai you were right in the first comment.  It really is that simple.  I'm now using templates from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@superflycss/component-test in https://www.npmjs.com/package/@superflycss/component-navbox via the https://www.npmjs.com/package/@superflycss/cli   Do you want to provide and official answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: Nope. It's not necessary :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick, as pointed out by @Aikon Mogwai:

```
nunjucks.configure('node_modules');
```

I have it implemented in [@superflycss/cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@superflycss/cli) in case anyone wants a reference implementation.